# Referencing extending type

Tags: typescript

I want to create a wrapper function that takes an options object and returns a model object based on it. Similar to how a Vue component is created from options object that contains props, data, methods, etc.

My problem is that the functions inside the options object should have access to all final model's properties via `this` (or any other parameter for that matter, but `this` *feels* nicer).

```ts
type Opts = {
  fields: { [k: string]: { label: string } | Opts }
  valid?: (this: Model<Opts>) => boolean
}

type Model<T extends Opts> = {
  [P in keyof T['fields']]: T['fields'][P] extends Opts
    ? Model<T['fields'][P]>
    : number
} & {
  readonly $meta: {
    /* some additional model details */
  }
}

function wrap<T extends Opts>(opts: T): Model<T> {
  // some wrapper implementation I don't care about here
}

const sample = wrap({
  fields: {
    x: { label: 'X' },
    y: { label: 'Y' },
    child: {
      fields: {
        p: { label: 'P' },
        q: { label: 'Q' },
      },
    },
  },
  valid() {
    // this here is Model<Opts>, not Model<full object>, containing x and y
    return this.x > 0 && this.child.p > 0
  },
})
```

I want `this` inside sample's `valid()` function to know about `this.x` and `this.y` and help me with auto-complete and type checking.

One option is to make Opts a generic type that extends itself `type Opts<T extends Opts<T>>` and then changing `valid` to

```
valid: (this: Model<Opts<T>>) => boolean
```

...but it's not really working out for me.

Comment: So would `this.p` and `this.q` be valid properties now? And `this.child` not?

Comment: `this.p` and `this.q` wouldn't be valid, but this.child and `this.child.p` and `this.child.q` would be valid.

Comment: can a `valid` field also be nested in the `child`? Would the nested `valid` then only have `p` and `q`  in `this`?

Comment: @TobiasS. yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `T` to represent the whole object, let's just use it to infer the keys of `fields`.

```
function wrap<T extends string>(opts: Opts<T>): Model<T> {
  // some wrapper implementation I don't care about here
}
```

We pass `T` to the `Opts` type to use as the keys of the `fields` type.

```
type Opts<T extends string> = {
  fields: { [k in T]: { label: string } }
  valid: (this: Model<T>) => boolean
}
```

We also pass `T` to the `Model` type to use it in its mapped type.

```
type Model<T extends string> = {
  [k in T]: number
} & {
  readonly $meta: { /* some additional model details */ }
}
```

This allows for auto-completion.

```
const sample = wrap({
  fields: {
    x: { label: 'X' },
    y: { label: 'Y' },
  },
  valid() {

    this.z // Error

    return this.x > 0 && this.y > 0
  },
})

sample.x
sample.y
sample.z // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwGcA8AVKEAewIDsAmCUCwATgJY4DmAfFALxQDeAUFFAGZkQA2BAXEygBtANZQKUFAF0BjKNwCGAIx4Di5KlAC%2021lABuC7mTwCAFMAAWZBAICyAezw9U1AJT1aShw%204QFOMxazMygkFCOztyo6Fi4BESkFDT0THqi4jiSMlA4AK4AtiokQVAAZGlsJP54DjjcIFAAJAUQwAqyUAD0AFREDq1QCnh4ZMBkdUZQBU48UM7tZNyEPV26wczseTgAxuN1UADuJApgMZjY%20ITqydRmDvC2sI%20ubvaz0Si0LGxdawgDaDHU6QEjiApgPytHDtfZZACS8zqAHJgFAdgpqkNvHk0ZYINUgiEdnViEQFBC-KlgWAzD8OFxeE96WwMJ1FCpuAJkQANZHaAA0ejYIHZylUUGRAE1%20VohWw5XpDMY8GYPCzumsrDYoPisTrIi44IhqALcg40YboltuNwoA4lAArCB7U3ouqLHDJKAYIb4KAgEJsNjahAAOgAXkHg9VgHkSFlQ2HfbQAAzlCpJxppvSKrRuEIICmQiDJ5hFymlwMVkuRoA)

Comment: Thanks for this alternative, but in reality I cant just make field keys as type parameter because my actual fields in real project can be of multiple types, not just `{ label: string }`. In my project the type `Opts` is closer to `type Opts = { 
  fields: { [k: string]: { label: string } | Opts }
  valid: (this: Model<???>) => boolean
}`.

I.e. it's more complicated potentially nested structure. So `T extends string` is unfortunately not sufficient.

Comment: @repka - Could you add this more complicated structure to your question? It's hard to try to answer a question when details are missing.

Comment: I edited the original post. Please have a look at the type of `fields` properties, as well as how they are mapped to `Model<T['fields'][P]>` if it's nested `Opts` or a simple `number` if it isn't. Thanks!